# Fortran FFTW with strides ''Matlab-like''

Tags: fortran, multidimensional-array, fftw, stride

I am a newbie in fortran, and trying to transform my matlab code efficiently to .f

I am using the fftw3 package and need ffts with strides complex to complex. **e.g.** 2 dimensions out of 3d array should be transformed.

What I do in matlab is

```
fft(fft(u,[],2),[],3)
```

where `u(Nx,Ny,Nz)` is 3d matrix.

I can do this in fortran via looping but this is much slower than matlabs ffts as in below;

```
call dfftw_plan_dft_2d(planf,Nx,Nz,inf,outf,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE)
do l=1,Nx;
    call dfftw_execute_dft_(planf,f(l,:,:),fh(l,:,:));
end do
```

`fft_many` is a solution to my problem where strides can be used, however I couldn't get it to work somehow. Could anyone help?

[This link](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Advanced-Complex-DFTs.html#Advanced-Complex-DFTs) is actually the 'C' help of fftw's advanced complex ffts;

Comment: No idea what the question is.

Comment: Don't expect the effort you put into translating your code from Matlab into Fortran to deliver a faster program.  Do not take this as a judgment on your Fortran skills, rather as an indication that Matlab uses highly-tuned implementations for much of its built-in functionality including FFTs.

Comment: using `f(1,:,:)` as an array argument can be very bad, as it's non-contiguous in memory and will probably result in a contiguous copy of the slice being passed to the subroutine.

Comment: I changed the periodic boundary conditions of mine from X&Z to X&Y which means with this configuration I needed fft(fft(u,[],2),[],1) for a u(Ny,Nx,Nz)and  this gets the job done in such a case;



  rank = 2;
  ppp(1) =Ny;  ppp(2) =Nx;
  howmany =Nz
  odist = ppp(1)*ppp(2);    idist =  ppp(1)*ppp(2); 
  ostride = 1;  istride = 1;
  inembed(:) = ppp(:); onembed(:) = ppp(:);

call dfftw_plan_many_dft(planf,rank,ppp,howmany,inf,inembed,istride,idist,outf, onembed,ostride,odist, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);


call dfftw_execute_dft(planf,f,fh);

Comment: Actually, MATLAB uses FFTW under the hood, at LEAST since version 12.